# Detecting calendar-event mail items in Office365 REST Mail API

Tags: exchange-server, office365

I am successfully retrieving user emails from our Exchange Online server, via REST requests and the ADAL library. We have been retrieving and processing calendar-event emails, and their associated calendar events, which are generated by Outlook, GMail/Google-Calendar, iPad, iPhone and Android devices.

We have been looking in the ClassName property for "meeting.request" or "meeting.cancelled", but those values were removed a week ago and have not returned. We have now been looking for a non-Null MeetingMessageType property (MeetingRequest or MeetingCancelled), but as of today, those properties have also been removed. This is incredibly valuable interop data but I don't know where to look next.

How can I associate a retrieved json Message object from a user's mailbox or a shared mailbox, with an (Exchange...) associated Calendar event? We can process Meeting creations, invitations, acceptances etc. with message items which we then purge; Whereas, querying the calendars for new and updated events is much much more intensive, since we certainly can't purge calendar events off the calendar as we process them!

Can I query the calendar for associated message Ids? I can't imagine this would be possible to do for every message.

Thanks!

Edit: @Venkat Thanks. Mail items are infinitely more process-able than emergent calendar-event standards. As an Exchange dev, I have to ask-- do you really need an example of how I can process a mail-bound event better as a mail item rather than a calendar event item? Ok that's cool, here is one:

One thing we are doing is cc/bcc-ing mail/mtg-requests to specific mailboxes for processing (or using client and server rules to accomplish the same thing). We can then poll individual mailboxes, shared mailboxes, and/or collections of mailboxes to auto-respond or not... and to move to specific calendars or not, and to redirect to specific users or not, and to change header information during routing for further category classification or not, and to even replace recipients/attendees or not etc. etc. To do the same thing with REST calendar requests, we'd lose all server rules automation, all client rules automation, procedural auto-respond, all headers manipulation (data-insertion/extraction), etc. We're just trying to push events to a cloud app, for certain collections of users, using shared mailboxes which redirect to specific daemon accounts, which hold calendars for specific subsets of our users/clients.

Like everyone else, we are trying to integrate with cloud apps. So we need procedural parsing, data-manipulation, and pushing of both mail and calendar items. So, for one thing, we have the massive advantages of server mail-processing rules, client/user mail rules, mail header modifications (easy item data modification), mail auto-respond control, and blind recipients. Calendar events don't get any of those things. For a second thing, we have a much more robust mail folders taxonomy than calendar(s) taxonomy (which is almost non-existent). For a third thing, Calendar event mail items are user-specific and have less persistent value than shared calendar events. Finally, if we're processing mail items any way-- why not at least have an eventId for events? Why take out ALL interop information? Having an eventId completely eliminates the need for a query against a calendar endpoint returning multiple items, and adds no addition queries against a mail endpoint.

Google includes an attached ics. Even if you eliminate the event item attachment from the API mail item, I don't see why you have to remove the eventId. Processing calendar events by mail is nothing new, but we have to have a data-binding between the two objects, to do it. That is all.

My Exchange Server still knows when a mail item is a calendar event. It just won't tell ~me~, any more, if I ask it over REST. So, as a brutish work-around I can set up a mail rule to add a category of "api_calendarEvent" for all incoming messages that are of type "Meeting Request". Then, after making a REST call for mail items, I can parse categories to manually repopulate a class property. But why remove the attachment, classname, MeetingMessageType, and EventId altogether from the mail item? Even if I made a server rule to re-categorize certain mail items in certain mailboxes as calendar events, and was able to know when to poll a calendar to get event details-- would I always know what calendar to poll, to find that event? All we'd need to avoid blind polling across multiple calendars, is for you to retain the EventId and/or ClassName. Then we'd also have massive automation of calendar processing again, which has currently been removed from the API.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Valleyspirit, Can you please explain a little more what processing you do based on the invite and meeting response mails?  Do you keep any state for each user?  You said querying calendars for new and updated events is much more intensive.  Can you please elaborate?  Knowing this info will help me recommend the right approach using the Office 365 REST APIs.  Thanks.

Comment: @VenkatAyyadevara-MSFT -- I have edited my question for you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Valleyspirit, I responded but had one additional question. If you are able to get all meeting invite and response messages through Me/MeetingMessages collection separate from Me/Messages collection, would that satisfy your scenarios? Or is it important for your scenario that the meeting related messages appear in the Me/Folders/Inbox/Messages feed along with all other messasges?  Let me know if my question is unclear or if you need more context.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the detailed response to my comment!  Your scenario is something we wish to support.  As part of schema clean up, we removed event ID and meeting message type from message, as it was being included for every message.  For calendar invites and responses, we plan to add back 2 properties:
1. A navigation link to the related event, so you can click to the event, and take actions on it, if you have calendar permissions.
2. A calendar response type e.g. Meeting Accepted, Meeting Declined etc., so you know what type of the page you have received.

We are currently working on the design and we don't have the exact timeline to share.  But, we will update our documentation as soon as we have this API available.

[UPDATE] We now return calendar event invites and responses as EventMessage which is a subclass of Message.  This entity includes a property called MeetingMessageType and a navigation link to the corresponding Event on the user's calendar.  See below for an example:

```
{
  @odata.context: "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#Users('<snipped>')/Messages/$entity",
  @odata.type: "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.EventMessage",
  @odata.id: "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users('<snipped>')/Messages('<snipped>')",
  @odata.etag: "<snipped>",
  Id: "<snipped>",
  ChangeKey: "<snipped>",
  Categories: [ ],
  DateTimeCreated: "2015-04-08T14:37:55Z",
  DateTimeLastModified: "2015-04-08T14:37:55Z",
  Subject: "<snipped>",
  BodyPreview: "",
  Body: {
    ContentType: "HTML",
    Content: "<snipped>"
  },
  Importance: "Normal",
  HasAttachments: false,
  ParentFolderId: "<snipped>",
  From: {
    EmailAddress: {
      Address: "<snipped>",
      Name: "<snipped>"
    }
  },
  Sender: {
    EmailAddress: {
      Address: "<snipped>",
      Name: "<snipped>"
    }
  },
  ToRecipients: [{
    EmailAddress: {
      Address: "<snipped>",
      Name: "<snipped>"
    }
  }],
  CcRecipients: [ ],
  BccRecipients: [ ],
  ReplyTo: [ ],       
  ConversationId: "<snipped>",
  DateTimeReceived: "2015-04-08T14:37:55Z",
  DateTimeSent: "2015-04-08T14:37:48Z",
  IsDeliveryReceiptRequested: null,
  IsReadReceiptRequested: false,
  IsDraft: false,
  IsRead: false,
  WebLink: "<snipped>",
  MeetingMessageType: "MeetingRequest",
  Event@odata.navigationLink: "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users('<snipped>')/Events('<snipped>')"
}
```

Please let me know if our proposed changes meet your requirements, if you have any questions or need more info.

Thanks,

Venkat

Comment: Thanks! Yes, AWESOME. That would return functionality for almost all our project scope. My main issue is that all calendar emails for ipad/iphone/android tablet/android phone/gmail calendar/MS Outlook, whether create/update/delete, could ALL be processed with the following message properties: ClassName, EventId, and MeetingMessageType. When all three of those were removed, our projects went dormant. Any interop data ya'll will be putting back in, will be absolutely awesome. I follow the improving documentation every day, and please pass on these needs. Thanks!

Comment: Re: a /Me/MeetingMessages collection: Yes, this would also be entirely reasonable, provided those messages contained some data similar to calendar response type and navigation link. Thanks, the endpoint is not too critical, I forgot to respond to this.

Comment: Hi valleyspirit, Thanks for the feedback!  Sorry for the delay in responding.  We are working to expose this information in some form that you can consume.  Stay tuned ...

Comment: Updated info w/ EventMessage support.  Thanks.